# How to add extra field in admin comment section

Tags: custom-field, comment-form

I wish to add extra field in post comment section while admin is logged in.

[Screenshot](http://www.diigo.com/item/image/19c1l/so7t)

I just add subject field in template comment form.But i couldn't store in db and retrieve it.

How can i do this ? Help me !

Answer (score 1):

You can add it directly through your functions.php, unfortunately this is not documented very well at all.

You want to hook into `add_comment_meta` using `add_action`, to look at this further refer to line 500-ish of comment.php.

It looks like this

```
function add_comment_meta($comment_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false) {

    return add_metadata('comment', $comment_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);

}
```

Comment: :could you please explain further. I couldn't see 500-ish line in comment.php. please

Comment: Just do a text search for `add_comment_meta` in comments.php, it is somewhat documented there, http://phpcrossref.com/wordpress/wp-includes/comment.php.html#add_comment_meta